# change text color in html via javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, colors

I'm trying to change title color as I write in html code below and the color of the color 
of the text doesn't change.
how can I change it?

```
 /**
     * Build a HTML table with the data
     */
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getTable = function () {
        var title =this.title.text; 
        var device = this.series[0].name;
        var unit = this.series[0].yAxis.axisTitle.text;

       // var html = '<table>',
        var html = '<h1 style="color:red">'+title+'</h1> <h2 style="color:red" >Device: '+device+'</h2><h2 style="color:red" >Unit: '+unit+'</h2>'+
        '<table>',
            rows = this.getDataRows();
        html += '</table>';
        return html;
    };
```

Thanks, Michal

Comment: You are *setting* the color in the code (well, you might call it changing it from the default), in a manner that works when tested in isolation, as you can see by testing just `<h1 style="color:red">foo</h1>` in a browser. So the problem is outside the code you posted. Please provide an actual (preferably minimal) example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I try to write to excel using html, and I want the titles to be red and I cant do it. The title stay black

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead of writing HTML code in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Your_element_Id").style.color="Any_color";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
document.getElementById("h1").style.color = "red";
```

via. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the same function on multiple elements, identified by their tagName (`h1`,`h2`, etc), I'd suggest:

```
function colorise() {
  // using the forEach method of the Array.prototype,
  // iterating over the array-like result of calling querySelectorAll():
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2'), function(h) {
    // h: the current array-element (in this case a node) of the array over 
    // which we're iterating.
    h.style.color = 'red';
  });

  // irrelevant, just to prevent subsequent (non-functional) clicks on the button:
  this.disabled = true;
  // further emphasising the disabled nature of the button:
  this.style.opacity = 0.5;
}

// finding the first <button> element, and adding an event-listener,
// listening for the 'click' event, and running a function in response:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', colorise);
```

```js
function colorise() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2'), function(h) {
    h.style.color = 'red';
  });
  this.disabled = true;
  this.style.opacity = 0.5;
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', colorise);
```

```html
<h1>H1 text</h1>
<h2>H2 text</h2>
<h1>More H1 text</h1>
<h2>And another h2</h2>

<button>Change the heading elements' text to red</button>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).